# Change class for a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a novice at jQuery and I've looked up online and with stack overflow search but can't get this working. I'm trying to change the class for a div on a mouse rollover.

My html for the div is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript-jQuery Sandbox Practice</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
        <script src="js/default.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="grid1">
                <div class="grid">Grid 01</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 02</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 03</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 04</div>
            </div>
            <div id="grid2">
                <div class="grid">Grid 05</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 06</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 07</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 08</div>
            </div>
            <div id="grid3">
                <div class="grid">Grid 09</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 10</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 11</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 12</div>
            </div>
            <div id="grid4">
                <div class="grid">Grid 13</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 14</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 15</div>
                <div class="grid">Grid 16s</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css for the div is:

```
.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

And hover css.

```
.grid_hover {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #3ca1ff;
}
```

My js for the div is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.grid').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('.grid_hover');     
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also, here is the site:
http://tiny.am/sandbox/Javascript-jQuery/

Edit: It seems all I had to do was reorder the .css. Before it was: (No work)

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
}

.grid_hover {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #3ca1ff;
}

#grid1 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#grid2 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#grid3 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#grid4 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

After its: (Worky)

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
}

.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.grid_hover {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #3ca1ff;
}

#grid1 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#grid2 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#grid3 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#grid4 {
    float: inherit;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not just using a css `:hover` state?

Comment: all you need to do is to change `.grid_hover` to `.grid:hover`

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('grid_hover');`  Take out the period, but like dwreck08 wrote, why not just use the hover state `:hover`

Comment: The hover state could give unexpected results on mobile clicking where jQuery will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `toggleClass`, you don't need to add the period to the class name. If you remove the period it works:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqnjdydg/)

```
$(this).toggleClass('grid_hover');
```

**NOT**

```
$(this).toggleClass('.grid_hover');
```

As a side note, you can do exactly what you want with css using the `:hover` state.

Comment: What's weird is I tried this as well, but it's not working on my page, hmmm. I see it working on the JS Fiddle example you linked. Gotta be something with the way I have it nested. Everything is in a container div then each group of 4 divs is in another div. When I try what I have in JSFiddle it doesn't work either so I'm close. I'm not targeting the nested/child (not sure what to call it) right. I'll keep working on it. This helped though.

http://tiny.am/sandbox/Javascript-jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:hover` CSS pseudo-class for this purpose, so that you won't need JavaScript at all.
There is also no need to repeat the unchanged CSS properties:

```
.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.grid:hover {
    background-color: #3ca1ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> use **$(this).toggleClass("grid_hover")** not $(this).toggleClass(".grid_hover")

```
 $(".grid").on("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("grid_hover");
    });
```

> you don't need to change class just simply apply this css you can get a desired output.

```
.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

> :hover is a pesudo class when you mouse over on ".grid" below css change will apply

```
.grid:hover {
    background-color: #3ca1ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `toggleClass`, `addClass` and `removeClass`, there is no need for the period before the class name.

You can also use the `mouseover` event.

```
$(".grid").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("grid_hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this. if you want the hover with jQuery

```
.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
} 

.grid:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #3ca1ff;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.grid').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('.grid_hover');     
    });
});
```

Enjoy !!!!

Comment: The jquery isn't doing anything in your example. The CSS is. You have no `.grid_hover` class in the css.